# Is it possible to use the Sun's gravity to gain significant delta-v?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, rocket-science, solar-system, space-mission

Someone asked [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43245) whether Sun's gravity has been used for delta-v gain, and from the answers it's not clear whether this is possible at all.

There is this rule of thumb that "burning fuel inside a deep gravity well is very efficient", but also "to reach close to the Sun, you need big delta-v". So, which consideration wins here?

Let's suppose our goal is to get out of Solar system with as much speed as possible. Is getting very close to Sun (e.g. 1 million km) going to help?

Comment: The  answers in Space Exploration SE address this point. eg  Oscar's answer : "If we were somehow to reach escape velocity from the Solar System (**which this method won't do**) ...  The planets rather than the Sun have the energy of motion we need for a slingshot acceleration." Or Martin's answer : "You can not get any extra energy relative to the Sun doing gravitational maneuver around the Sun. (This applies generally of course.)"

Comment: There is also this note at the end of one answer: *there are some ways to gain an energy from gravity field if you are doing (significant) propulsion burns along the way*. I want to know if this effect is usable.

Comment: See also [Could the Sun be used as 
 gravity assist outside the solar system with current technology?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/829/could-the-sun-be-used-as-a-gravity-assist-outside-the-solar-system-with-current)

Comment: @user27542 Posting a comment below a post is the best way to get clarification of the meaning of that post IMO. I guess that Martin is referring to the [Oberth Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect), which you seem to be aware of. Questions about the physics of such a manoeuvres are suitable here, but questions about the practicalities of using the effect are better asked at Space Exploration SE.